# Angular-ui ui-select - force dropdown to show above

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select

So I have some controls in a fixed position to the bottom of the screen for easy reach on mobile, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to make the option content appear above the select menu.

[image: dropdown content falls out of view when at the bottom of the screen]

I tried messing with `append-to-body="true"` and some other stuff that was totally off the wall. I feel like this should be a simple hook but not finding anything..

Answer (score 3):

Add `position='up'` to `<ui-select-choices>`.

Other options include down and auto (top/down depending on available space).

Demo: https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-dropdown-position.html

Edit on Plunker available at https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/

[Dropdown Position]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it with css by adjusting the absolute positioning.. This is actually kind of nice because I could control when it happened this way, for me it was only for mobile screen widths.

```
.some-container-class .ui-select-choices {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! It might just be a difference in versions, but I had to add this to .ui-select-dropdown instead of .ui-select-choices though.